# How do I add 3 different licenses with 3 different prices in django Models

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a product and I wanted to add three purchase options that depend on the license you buy.

For example:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    productname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    license  = models.????
```

> There should be a multiselector here in order to select all three
> licenses when applicable. But how?

```
discription = models.TextField()
image = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)

class License(models.Model):
```

> Here should be some kind of choice field that connects the price to
> the choice.... but how???

Help please.
I tried this and it didn't work

```
class Song(models.Model):
    class License(models.IntegerChoices):
        BASIC = 35
        PREMIUM = 50
        PROFESSIONAL = 150
        FREE = 0

    license = models.IntegerField(choices=License.choices,  default='License.FREE') 
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Comment: This looks like a `ManyToManyField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to keep Product outside of licenses as it will be same for all pricing models.

You can store license info for user in the User model directly or in some custom model that is assigned to the user as `OneToOne` and contains extra fields for that user.

For pricing, you will just define different prices for each license and product. To make it simpler, you can add `ProductPrice` as an `inline` for the `Product` admin.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...product related fields here like name and etc.
    default_price = models.FloatField("Default price", default=0.0)

    def user_price(self, user):
        """Will return ProductPrice model or None if there is no results."""
        return self.prices.filter(license=user.license).first()


class License(models.Model):
    """
    I would recommend using a custom user model or OneToOne model where you can
    assign which license the user have and use `user.license` for that license
    value or user.information.license if you use OneToOne model.
    """
    ...fields related to the License definition only.


class ProductPrice(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="prices"
    )
    license = models.ForeignKey(
        License, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="prices"
    )
    price = models.FloatField("Price", default=0.0)
    ...other fields related to license pricing if you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone that responded. the solution was actually pretty straight forward. It was just like Emin said. I need to make licensing it's own class and a product pricing class with licensing and price. So thanks everything is working